# Delete Empty Columns VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to delete all of the empty columns in my worksheet. I found some code online, but it is not working as I wish.

```
Sub deleteEmptyColumns()
    ' Set variables
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngLastColumn As Long
    ' Get last column
    lngLastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    ' Turn off screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Loop from last column cell to 1
    For i = lngLastColumn To 1 Step -1
        ' Check if column has any values
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(i)) = 0 Then
            ' Delete column
            Columns(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
    ' Turn on screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot of my workbook. There are lots of empty columns, and I would like to delete them.
[image: Data]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is happening when you run it?

Comment: And BTW, COUNTA will count a cell if it has a space or a formula that returns `""`

Comment: @Scott Craner nothing is happening

Comment: Nothing happens @Scott Craner

Comment: Then you will need to do some debugging on your own.  Step through the code and make sure that the counta is not finding something it should not.

Comment: @Scott Craner so if a cell has a space, will this code not work?

Comment: Correct, if any cell in the columns has a formula or a space or any other unprintable character then it will be counted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235803/discussion-between-zane-patterson-and-scott-craner).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming missing data is missing uniformly and last row is data and not totals or something else the following solution should work even if there are formulas but the formulas will not work after this solution so back things up:

```
Sub Delete_Empty_Columns()

Dim Last_Column_No As Long
Dim Last_Row_No As Long
Dim i As Long

Last_Column_No = Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1).Column
Last_Row_No = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Row - 1    

'Coppy everything in used range and paste only values back
'This will clear all formulas
ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Cells(Last_Row_No, Last_Column_No)).Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

For i = 1 To Last_Column_No
    If Cells(Last_Row_No, i) = "" Then
        Columns(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```